# Prevent Duplicate Entries in SQL

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008, duplicates

How do I prevent a duplicate entry from a text field by using SQL Query?

Comment: Is the field `text` datatype or is it `varchar` containing text?  It's a big difference...

Comment: its a varchar containing text

Comment: And what is the length definition?

Comment: Are you trying to return non-duplicated entries, or are you trying to prevent the user from inserting a duplicate value?

Comment: Im trying to prevent the user from inserting a duplicate value

Answer (score 2):

The feature in SQL Server to prevent duplicate entries is called a [UNIQUE INDEX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188783.aspx).

However the maximum size of the column must be at most 900 bytes:

> [...] The maximum allowable size of the combined index values is 900 bytes.
>
> Columns that are of the large object (LOB) data types ntext, text, varchar(max), nvarchar(max), varbinary(max), xml, or image cannot be specified as key columns for an index.

If your text is larger than this then it is not possible to use a unique index and you probably need to consider whether restricting duplicate values is really the correct solution for whatever problem you have. If you think you need a unique index on text that could be thousands of bytes longer, the chances are that you're solving the wrong problem.

However you also could consider cryptographically hashing the content (e.g. MD5, SHA1, etc...) and adding a unique index to the hash. While the hash can in theory give collisions for different texts, this is unlikely to happen in practice unless your data is coming from an untrusted source (e.g. user data). In this case you need to consider the security implications of a hash collision and make sure that you choose a sufficiently strong cryptographic hash function.

Comment: See his comment, looks like it's actually varchar.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to prevent the insertion of duplicate rows, you can add a unique index:

`CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ix_IndexName ON MyTable(MyUniqueField) WITH IGNORE_DUP_KEY = <ON/OFF>`

If you set the `IGNORE` option to `ON` then duplicate rows will just be ignored.  If it's set to `OFF` then duplicates will generate an error and stop the insert.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DISTINCT`. See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259187%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) link

Like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    YourTable.textField
FROM
    YourTable
```

Comment: We have no idea if this actually addresses the issue since the OP is so vague.

Comment: He's not vague, but he is asking the same question multiple times  (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229990/preventing-duplicate-values-entered-by-user)