# Preventing Duplicate values entered by user

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008

How do I prevent users from a inserting a duplicate value using SQL Query
datatype is VarChar(50)

e.g. the name field has already been defined as "Josh", I don't want it to be able to add another "Josh"

Answer (score 3):

Set unique key constraint in the database field. But this would throw an SQLException which you will need to catch to display a proper error message to the user.

More on Unique keys... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191166.aspx

Comment: is setting unique key the only method to prevent duplicate entries?

Comment: You can also create a unique index. That's only different from creating a unqiue constraint in terms of TSQL syntax. Behavior is just about identical.

Comment: Or you can use Triggers (http://www.sqlteam.com/article/an-introduction-to-triggers-part-i) I would stick with Unique Keys.

Comment: You could also check to see if the value exists before saving.  But that is what Unique Key does anyway.